# My footer is elevating to the middle on small screens

Tags: css, reactjs, footer

So i have a footer on my page that is wrapped around a container and the footer wrapper but everytime i decrease the size of the screen the footer is elevating to the middle of the screen how can i fix it so the footer is always on the bottom of the page? This is the css of the container and the footer wrapper:

```
const FooterWrapper = styled.div`
display: flex;
margin: 60px;
margin-top: 0;

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
`;
const Container = styled.div`
width: 68%;

background-color: white;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;

height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;


border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;


-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;


@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  transform: none;
  top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  justify-content: space-between;

  ${({page}) => page === 'bem-vindo' && css`
    height: 76.6vh;
  `}

  ${({page}) => page === 'plano' && css`
    height: 83.5vh;
  `}

  position: relative;
}
`;
```